# How to make DatagramSocket always to be receiving Packets for android

Tags: java, android, udp

I know how to receive packets but I want my app to always check to packets that received

```
public void controlListener(){
    control.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            switch(receiveData().charAt(0)){
            case '1':{
                Log.d("","1");
                setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                control.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            case '3':{
                Log.d("","3");
                setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                control.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Thread thread = new Thread()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {



                            Log.d("", "here");
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                            switch(receiveData().charAt(0)){
                            case '1':{
                                Log.d("", "1");
                                setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                control.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                            }
                            case '3':{
                                Log.d("", "3");
                                setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                control.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                break;
                            }
                            case '4':{
                                Log.d("", "4");
                                setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                control.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                break;
                            }
                            default:{
                                Log.d("","not expecting this");
                            }
                            }
                                }
                            });


                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

                thread.start();

                break;
            }
            case '4':{
                Log.d("","4");
                setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                control.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            default:{
                Log.d("","not expecting this");
            }
            }



        }
    });
}
```

What I wanted to do once I receive a 3 too keep receiving until i receive either a 1 or a 4.  and allow the user to use the buttons while its a 3. If a 1 or 4 make all of the buttons invisible till a receive a 3.

Answer (score 0):

So as you said you have to use a worker thread to permanently execute

```
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
socket.receive(packet);
```

and also in that thread you need a Handler, which should be created on the UI thread and a WeakReference to your Activity to prevent memory leaks and have ability to update UI. So when you receive new package you can do like this

```
handler.post(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
          // do something with received string and activity
     }
}
```

Comment: Im still having trouble the thread works but all of the buttons get disabled I can touch until the thread is done then it basically freezes but doesnt crash

Comment: I would suggest you post everything what you have written

Comment: where the switch statement is where I want the thread to start and receive the packets and check if i get a 1 or 4 but allow buttons to be pressed while the thread is running

Comment: You are not starting any thread in your code, the easiest way to start it is to write `new Thread(Runnable run).start()`.

Comment: I did that now I know the thread is running and receiving packets but it wont allow me to use the buttons until it finishes or it freezes the button but the application doesnt crash.  I have tried runOnuithread also and the handler post.